# Gtk2hs invalid signals

Tags: haskell, ghc, gtk2hs

I'm running a very simple "hello world" GUI program. (Saved as gui.hs) My code is:

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

main = do
  initGUI
  window <- windowNew
  widgetShowAll window
  onDestroy window mainQuit
  mainGUI
```

I compile with: `ghc -L/usr/lib gui`

It compiles fine, but when I run it I see:

```
objc[51245]: Class GNotificationCenterDelegate is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib and /opt/local/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

(process:51245): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gsignal.c:2423: signal 'destroy' is invalid for instance '0x7fe9dc81a0e0' of type '(null)'
```

The window appears, but it won't quit when I click to close the window. (Window disappears, but the process doesn't terminate.)

This is a very simple example- I've tried making buttons that trigger signals, but I (almost) always get this "signal is invalid" warning.

I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan with GHC 8.4.3 (Haskell platform), and I installed everything following instructions here: (section 2)
[https://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Mac]

I am starting to feel like my installation is messed up somehow? Maybe do I need to have installed GHC also with brew? Is there any way I can test the installation (other than trying what I'm already doing)? Are the two runtime warnings related to each other? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm far from an expert on Mac, but it looks like you may have installed glib twice in two different places, and GHC isn't sure which one to use. I'm not too sure how to solve it, but `brew uninstall glib` _may_ work.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer: I fixed this by removing the Haskell Platform and reinstalling GHC with brew. Then all worked fine.